# How to tell if a Float is in a range?

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to write a program in VBScript that can tell whether or not a user input is within a previously defined range that consists of a variable + or - 0.05,

However, I cannot get past the issues associated with Floating point numbers and rounding.

An example of what I am trying to do is below

```
H4 = (user input)
H420 = 10.06 /this is one of the previously defined variables
H425= 10.00 /another previously defined variable
Tol = 0.001 /this is how close the float needs to be to be considered close enough

If H425 - 0.05 >= H4 <= H420 + 0.05

    Return True
```

Comment: Is it a real code? You can't do such comparisons in VBSscript. Split it to two comparisons with 'and'. Like `H425 - 0.05 >= H4 and H4 <= H420 + 0.05`

Answer (score 0):

VBScript doesn't have a "between" type of construct, so you need to split your expression in two distinct clauses and combine them with the `And` operator.

```
If (H4 <= H425 - 0.05) And (H4 <= H420 + 0.05) Then
    '...
End If
```

Also, your logic is ... unusual.

```
   H425 - 0.05 ≥ H4 ≤ H420 + 0.05
⇔ 10.00 - 0.05 ≥ H4 ≤ 10.06 + 0.05
⇔         9.05 ≥ H4 ≤ 10.11
```

Simply comparing `H4` to the smaller reference value (`H425`) would be sufficient. Checking if `H4` is smaller than *both* reference values shouldn't be required unless there are situations where `H420` can actually be smaller than `H425 - 0.1`.